# Why is this not in the tail sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots\in \mathbb{R}$ be i.i.d. and let $S_n=X_1+\cdots +X_n$.

I see why $$\{ \omega: S_n(\omega)\in A \textrm{ i.o.}\}$$ is permutable, but why is this not in the tail $\sigma$-field? The fact that it occurs infinitely often implies that it should be in the tail $\sigma$-field, right?

Comment: Because changing the value of $X_1(\omega)$ changes every $S_n(\omega)$ hence this might change the fact that $S_n(\omega)$ is in $A$ for infinitely many $n$s or not. By contrast, the event $$\{n^{-1}S_n\in A\ \text{i.o.}\}$$ is in the tail sigma-algebra. Can you prove this?

Comment: But wouldn't your first sentence imply that the set isn't permutable then?

Comment: No. What does permutable mean to you?

Comment: $\{\omega: \omega\in A\} = \{\omega: \pi\omega\in A\}$ where $\pi$ is a permutation of finitely many $\omega_i$'s.

Comment: Then changing $\omega_1$ (and leaving $\omega_k$ unchanged for every $k\geqslant2$) makes the event quite non-permutable, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh nevermind I see--thanks!

Comment: You can post your own answer to the question - otherwise it will remain marked as "unanswered" indefinitely.